# Material UI Dialog not working in production - shows a blank page

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, serve

I've installed `serve` and have run `npm run build`. When I start the application everything's working except the dialogs i.e. when I open them I get a blank white screen and an error:

```
react-dom.production.min.js:156 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at ri (2.3c107e85.chunk.js:2)
    at gi (2.3c107e85.chunk.js:2)
    at Object.Oi [as useEffect] (2.3c107e85.chunk.js:2)
    at Object.t.useEffect (2.3c107e85.chunk.js:2)
    at w (2.3c107e85.chunk.js:2)
    at S (2.3c107e85.chunk.js:2)
    at 2.3c107e85.chunk.js:2
    at ai (2.3c107e85.chunk.js:2)
    at Ni (2.3c107e85.chunk.js:2)
    at Vu (2.3c107e85.chunk.js:2)
```

If I start the application with the normal setup i.e. without serve, the dialogs start to work as expected.
I'm not sure what's causing this.

Comment: You need to show more code for us to evaluate it. Seems like its a problem in your useEffect not with material-ui.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem and I solved using the variable condition "openFlag" as a condition rendering, like this:

```
{ openFlag && <Dialog open={openFlag}> ... </Dialog>}
```